# Exclude matches between two tables Sqll vb2013

Tags: mysql

```
Table Invoice
     Fields - CustCode,DrawingNumber,DrawingRevision

Table Inventory
     Fields - CustCode,DrawingNumber,DrawingRevision
```

I'm trying to make a query to List all DrawingNumbers with DrawingRevision from Table Invoice where CustCode = 7
that is not already in in table Inventory

if an item is in inventory with a specific revision.
I want to create a list, to select from that won't duplicate the same item
I'm using vb2013 ( I tried using Exist but I keep getting an error )

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

*I'm trying to make a query to List all DrawingNumbers with DrawingRevision from Table Invoice where CustCode = 7 that is not already in in table Inventory*

Assuming you are defining an item by DrawingNumber and DrawingRevision then try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Invoice
WHERE CustCode=7 AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Inventory 
                  WHERE Invoice.DrawingNumber = Inventory.DrawingNumber AND
                        Invoice.DrawingRevision = Inventory.DrawingRevision)
```

Comment: Thank you.   The Code did what I asked. Now that I see the results I see what I needed is to

Comment: @MikeLynch Great. If this is what you were after do you want to accept the answer